# web scrape a progress bar in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium

I am scraping different projects from the following website https://indiainvestmentgrid.gov.in/opportunities/nip-project/606803. There is a progress bar on this webpage that shows a project stage (under conceptualisation - completed). Do you have any suggestions how can I scrape this?

I am using RSelenium, extracting the page source and looking through it in the following way:

```
remDr$navigate('https://indiainvestmentgrid.gov.in/opportunities/nip-project/606803')
url <- read_html(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]])

project_title <- url %>% 
    html_nodes(".prj-name") %>%
    html_text()
```

However, I am not sure how to scrape this progress bar. Selector Gadget shows that the completed circles/bars are signed as ".active-stage", but I cannot find it in my HTML code. In the case of this project, it should be scraped as "Under Implementation".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you are using both `RSelenium` and `rvest`. Also, mind that `html_nodes` is deprecated.
The coloring is of the bars is (I think) defined by the projectStageID. The following should work for most of those pages.

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr

url <- "https://indiainvestmentgrid.gov.in/opportunities/nip-project/606801"

out <- read_html(url)

out %>%
  html_elements(css = "#projectStageId") %>%
  as.character  %>%
  substr(start = 49, stop = nchar(.)-2) %>%
  switch(
    "500020" = "Under Conceptualization",
    "600037" = "Under Development",
    "500021" = "Under Implementation",
    "500023" = "Completed",
    NA
  )
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! Though can you please elaborate a bit on the part starting from substr? I do not understand it fully yet, and it might be very useful for me in the future

Comment: using `substr()` you can extract a piece of a string, starting from and ending at a position in that string. We're only interested in the part of the string that tells us something useful, which in this case starts at the 49th letter (white spaces included). the `nchar(.)-2` bit is not necessary here, but its more general, in the case you find an ID strings that is a different length. the `.` in the `nchar()` is a placeholder dot (https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/reference/pipe.html), basically saying "whatever is on the left-hand side, I want it again here)

Comment: `out %>%  html_element("#projectStageId") %>% html_attr("value") %>% switch........`